# JQUery: Filter select elements from a .map query

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, html

I'm sure this has been answered here but I just don't know how to word the question. I am getting all of the elements of a form using:

```
//get all form elements
$("#" + thisForm + " :input").map(function () { 

//get element data
var elementName = $(this).attr('name');
var elementType = $(this).attr('type');
```

and then storing them in a javascript object. The problem is that select and textarea elements do not have a type, so they appear as undefined. Is there a way to filter for them using the :input").map function or do I  have to go to something like this:

```
$(thisForm + " > fieldset > select").add(thisForm + " > fieldset > textarea").each(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I am unsure what you want to achieve here.

Comment: I'm getting all the elements from a form. I'm then looking to sort those elements by type (radios, checkboxes, selects). However, select and textarea do not have a type attribute so the way I am currently doing it returns elementType as undefined. As I am mapping over all the elements how can I determine it's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the returned `elementType` is `undefined`, you can try getting the `tagName` property (plain Javascript `HTMLElement` property) which will return the name of the tag itself (like `select`, `textarea`, etc.).

So you can do something like:

```
var elementType = $(this).attr('type');
if (typeof elementType == 'undefined') {
    elementType=this.tagName.toLowerCase();
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TxYm7/1/)